# Segmentation fault in insertion-sort in C

Tags: c, sorting, insertion-sort

I'm trying to write an algorithm that sorts elements in a list in increasing order (insertion sort). I start the main function by defining all the following variables (and arrays) as int. 
Here is the sorting function:

```
void sort(int a, int b , int list[], int i)
{
    for(i=1; i<(b); i++)
    {
        while(list[i-1]>list[i])
        {
            a = list[i-1];
            list[i-1]=list[i];
            list[i]=a;
            i--;
        }
    }
}
```

b being the number of elements in the list, and a being initialized as 0 in main.

When in the main function I use sort with a table of positive integers, it sorts them in the desired way. However, if some of the values are negative, the program produces a segmentation fault.

Could somebody help me figure out the error? Thank you!

Comment: A segmentation fault almost surely means you are accessing memory that does not belong to you.  Study your inner loop.  Do you see any way that you might access `list` via an index less than 0 or greater than the number of elements less one?

Comment: It's usually a bad idea to change the value of `i` yourself inside the for loop which uses `i` as the loop increment.  When you decrement i the first time inside the while loop, it becomes 0, and then you are trying to accesss `list[-1]`

Comment: @bruceg Debatable (I do that a lot when writing parsers to skip characters), but in this case it certainly is.

Answer (score 2):

In the first loop (i.e. when `i` is 1) then this part

```
while(list[i-1]>list[i])
```

is the same as

```
while(list[0]>list[1])
```

which is OK. Now assume that `list[0]>list[1]` is true. Then you will do:

```
    a = list[i-1];     ---> same as a = list[0];
    list[i-1]=list[i]; ---> same as list[0]=list[1];
    list[i]=a;         ---> same as list[1]=a;
    i--;               ---> Now i becomes 0
```

which is also OK. But the next statement will be

```
while(list[i-1]>list[i])  ---> same as while(list[-1]>list[0])
                                                  ^^
                                                  Illegal access
```

The illegal access is likely to be the cause of the seg fault.